# getaddrinfo: Name or service not known with LdapAuthenticatable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, ldap

I'm trying to connect to a LDAP Server via Ruby on Rails with the LdapAuthenticatable Gem for Devise.

It works fine via openldap, so apparently no issues with /etc/hosts or firewall. I use this code: https://github.com/heartcombo/devise/wiki/How-To:-Authenticate-via-LDAP

I tried both hostnames and IP addresses, but no luck.

```
if params[:user]
      ldap = Net::LDAP.new
      ldap.host = '134.102.200.4' # only accessible from internal network
      ldap.port = 389
      ldap.auth username, password

      if ldap.bind
        user = User.find_or_create_by(username: username)
        success!(user)
      else
        return fail(:invalid_login)
      end
    end
```

Error Message: Net::LDAP::Error in LoginController#create - getaddrinfo: Name or service not known

Thanks for your help!